How to get Xbox Live session from XUID using the Xbox REST API?
I'm attempting to get Xbox Live sessions by an XUID like this:
curl -is -X GET "https://sessiondirectory.xboxlive.com/serviceconfigs/4fc10100-5f7a-4470-899b-280835760c07/sessiontemplates/MinecraftLobby/sessions?xuid=<xuid>" -H "Authorization: XBL3.0 x=<userhash>;<token>" -H "x-xbl-contract-version: 105"

I'm running Minecraft: Bedrock Edition on my alt account, and upon running this with the XUID of my alt, the response is always {result:[]}
I've tried everything from changing the contract version to playing on different accounts, but the same response is always given. I've checked multiple times if the game is running on my alt, and it is.
I have the currentPlayers, groupId, joinRestriction, maxPlayers, platform, sequenceNumber and titleId of the game. The issue is that I cannot get the multiplayer session id of the game from the session directory.

Using the URL "https://multiplayeractivity.xboxlive.com/activities/query/dashboard" we can set the header for Authentication to our Xbox token and set the method to POST and give the body:
{
  "users": [
    "<xuid>"
  ]
}

The response should contain lots of information about the game that user is playing, including the session name and scid (Session Config ID)
